# SVG fonts not working on iOS

Tags: ios, svg, font-face, arabic

I converted these arabic fonts to work with CSS @font-face, and they do work on desktop but not on iOS. I tried quite a few things as suggested on other threads but no joy.

This is the page: http://bit.ly/WuBnaa <- works great on desktop, not on iOS.

Comment: wow, why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no svg font in your @font-face, see [here](http://i4ideas.net/fatemi52/fatemi52.css):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlFatemi52';
    src: url('http://i4ideas.net/fatemi52/alfatemi152-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://i4ideas.net/fatemi52/alfatemi152-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://i4ideas.net/fatemi52/alfatemi152-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://i4ideas.net/fatemi52/alfatemi152-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you do convert the above to an svg font as well, make sure that you get the arabic ranges too (most conversion services online strip everything outside the ascii range).

Comment: I removed the SVG after starting this thread. As for arabic ranges, I did make sure "no subsetting" was selected and the demo page of font-squirrel did show several arabic glyphs.

Comment: I've seen font-squirrel svgfonts being broken many times (wrong id's), so check that if you haven't already. An example: see your `src: url(webfont.svg#thisID)`, open the webfont.svg file and check that there's a font element with an `id` attribute with the value `thisID`. Also, have you seen this blogpost? http://ixdc.net/blog/2011/01/05/css-arabic-custom-fonts-on-ios/?

Answer (score -1):

To sum up: WebKit on iOS doesn't support the SVG format.

You will have to come up with another format, as no one knows (except Apple) when will this be implemented (if it ever is).

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it works, http://smashingmagazine.com uses font-face and all fonts work on iPad

Comment: Infact, the english glyphs from the font I'm using works, just the Arabic ones don't. For Arabic, it uses the default iOS arabic font for some reason.

Comment: Well, not everything works, check it here: http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html