# Google web fonts on ipad

Tags: ios, css, web, fonts, font-face

I am using some Google web fonts for my website, Arabic fonts, from here http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess

I import these fonts in my css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabicnaskh.css);
```

The fonts work just fine everywhere but not on ipad. I tried to google the issue and I came up with this [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600147/svg-fonts-not-working-on-ios) that suggests SVG. Any clues on how to get SVG for Google web fonts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't read all of the terms of use, but they give you access to download the font. I believe you can then take that font to [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and it will generate you the font types you need (and CSS @font-face styles) so you can self-host the font yourself.

Comment: I tried to do this already but the fonts are not working, sounds like there is a problem with Font Squirrel in converting Arabic fonts

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, Google fonts don't have SVG format in their defaults of these fonts, I had to download them and get the SVG format, re-include my fonts and it worked well so far on [iPad Peek](http://ipadpeek.com/), with test them and get a final feedback